# How to plot bar graph for top five game for each genre using for loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, data-analysis

```
genre_game=group_game.groupby(["Genre","Name"])"Global_Sales"].sum().reset_index().sort_values(["Genre","Global_Sales"],ascending=(True,False))

       
genre_game
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tqFR.png)

```
genre_s=df["Genre"].unique()
genre_sorted=sorted(genre_s)
print(f'List of : {genre_sorted}' )
```

List of : ['Action', 'Adventure', 'Fighting', 'Misc', 'Platform', 'Puzzle', 'Racing', 'Role-Playing', 'Shooter', 'Simulation', 'Sports', 'Strategy']

```
def f(genre):
    for genre  in genre_sorted:
        
        
        plt.bar(genre_game[genre][:5],genre_game["Global_Sales"][genre:genre+5])
        plt.xticks(rotation=90)
        
        
f("Adventure")
```

Comment: Please don't post data/code/error messages as images. Post the text directly here on SO.

Comment: Will keep  that in mind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it without a loop. This example here groups by the top 2 largest sales, but you can change 2 to 5 or any number.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

genre = ['Action', 'Action', 'Action', 'Strategy', 'Strategy', 'Strategy']
name =['GTAV', 'GTAIV', 'FIFA13', 'Worms2', 'Tropico', 'WarOverworld']
sales = [55, 13, 16, 1, 1, 0.5]
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(genre, name, sales)), 
                  columns=['genre', 'name', 'sales'])

df2 = df.groupby('genre') \
                 .apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(2, 'sales')) \
                 .reset_index(drop=True) 

plt.bar(df2.name, df2.sales)
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('% global')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Here is what the source `df` looks like:
[image]
And here is what the top 2 `df2` looks like: 
[image]

Comment: I really like the way the way you approached the method to group the data frame, but still my question of plotting bar graph for specific Genre with out using if else remains unanswered.

Comment: def f(genre):
    

    if genre=="Action":
        plt.bar(df2.Name[:5], df2.Global_Sales[:5])
        
    elif genre=="Adventure":
        plt.bar(df2.Name[5:10], df2.Global_Sales[:5])

Comment: I don't want to use if esle for every loop, can you please help me to solve that too

Comment: @RishabhGupta, please revise your question with (1) a better example dataset; (2) an example of your expected output; and (3) statement of your problem, including why you want or don't want to use a loop or if/then condition. For (1), you can see from my example how easy it is to include a dataframe in your question. If you give a good example dataset, then it should be easy to just sketch a picture for (2). For (3), your comments here are confusing because you say you want to use if/then in one comment and say you don't want to use it in another comment. When you fix these, we can help you.